# How to use wordpress with Git?

Tags: git

Hi guys wonder if there is something like a guide to use git to manage WP projects. I have always been a cowboy coder, and I need to make this shift to Git to become more standarized...how can I begin? at least i would love to have my theme in GIT to have a backup copy of it and be able to track the changes. Im the only person working on the project, but I need to prepare myself for future jobs so I want to test this GIT+WP.

Comment: Actually..., What stopped you?

Comment: what? sorry i dont understand what you refer to...

Comment: I meant what have you tried? What the problem you faced using git with WordPress?

Comment: i have never used git, i use wp to make sites, i want to lear to use git with wp...but is the first thing i will use git for. any recommmendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You questioned:

> *How to use wordpress with Git?*

Actually your question is a bit wrong, and should actually be:

> **How to use Git with WordPress?**

As git is for controlling versions so using it depends upon you what actually you want to take under version controlling. I personally develop WordPress themes and plugins so I control versions, specific to themes and plugins only.

#### For Themes

When developing a theme (i.e. `my-theme` is the folder name), I get into it:

```
cd my-theme
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Started developing the theme"
```

In this way I manage all the versions of my development phase to that particular theme. But in the meantime WordPress can be updated, several plugins can be updated, and the `/uploads/` folder can be updated too - I don't care actually. I just think about code and that's all.

In some cases I want the database to be version controlled too. In that case I export all the database tables into a `.zip` file and put it inside the theme into a `_db_` folder and then add and commit.

#### For Plugins

Within my Plugin (i.e. `my-plugin` is the folder name), I follow the similar steps to control versions of my plugin.

#### For whole WordPress Project

To control versions of the whole WordPress project, get into the project folder and initiate git there to catch all the changes to the project.

```
project\
   .git\
   wp-admin\
   wp-content\
   wp-includes\
   ...
```

That's all what came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

hello fellow cowboy coder, I have been dabbling away with wp and git for some time. I have some projects stored on GIT, but they are there purely in a collaborative format. WP have there own repository for wp themes. Git is fairly straight forward to set up, there is a GUI for GIT, but its much more efficient to use the command line approches. GIT only gets messy when you are working with large teams updating into a project, since your the only Developer, you would be mainly doing git push's and only need to pull when your deploying the files.